# Flutter - TimeOfDay to Firestore timestamp then into DateTime?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timeofday

I have two fields of type TimeOfDay in a model class, which is called startTime and endTime, how do i store this type into a firestore field, as a Timestamp somehow?  What i want to achieve is to pick a time like start: 12:00 , end: 13:00 from a timepicker then store it to firestore, and then when reading from firestore i need the time to be of type DateTime, in the format of "12:00" in order to work with this in the weekday calendar widget where the start and end time properties is of type DateTime. Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds possible.  I suggest giving it a try, and if it doesn't work, post the code along with a description of what it's doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Facing a similar issue. What did you implement?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, i got to abandon the project for other reasons, but would still know how this could be done